# How to check if a marker is in a cluster?

Tags: leaflet.markercluster

With [Leaflet.Markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), how is it possible to check if a marker is in a cluster?

Answer (score 2):

### **Use Leaflet's hasLayer() function**

Regular visible markers technically exist as layers in the map. Leaflet also has a function [hasLayer()](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/reference.html#map-haslayer) that returns true/false whether a given reference, like a stored marker, currently exists (ie "is visible") in the map as a layer.

### How I used it

For my specific problem having to do with marker clusters, I gave a special visual decoration to a selected map marker (e.g. red border), and this decoration remained even after that particular marker went in-and-out of a cluster. I needed the selected marker to deselect itself if it entered a cluster.

Below is rough logic that allows me to check whether a given marker reference is visible to the user after a cluster event (that may occur for any reason, like zoom events or non-user driven movements in the map).

**Relevant abbreviated code:**

I hold my clustering like this...

```
this.markersClustered = L.markerClusterGroup({ // Lots of stuff here... } })
```

In my click event for individual markers, I store the marker in a "selectedItem" object (which I use for all kinds of other logic in my app)...

```
onEachFeature(feature, marker) {
    marker.on("click", e => {

        // ... (lots of code) ...

        // Save instance of the marker; I call it "layer" only
        // because I only use this for the hasLayer() check
        this.selectedItem.layer = marker

        // Here do other stuff too, whatever you need...
        //this.selectedItem.target = e.target
        //this.selectedItem.latlng = e.latlng
        //this.selectedItem.id = e.target.feature.id
        //this.selectedItem.icon = layer._icon

        // ... (lots of code) ...

    })
}
```

When cluster animations end, using `hasLayer()`, check whether the selected marker is in a cluster, and do stuff.

Note: the check is done at the END of clustering animation in my use case, because I didn't want the user to see the selected marker lose it's special visual decoration while the clustering animation was happening (it would appear buggy).

```
this.markersClustered.on('animationend', (e) => {

  // Check visibility of selected marker

  if(this.map.hasLayer(this.selectedItem.layer)) {
      // True: Not in a cluster (ie marker is visible on map)
  } else {
      // False: In a cluster (ie marker is not visible on map)
  }

  console.log("Selected marker visible?:" +  this.map.hasLayer(this.selectedItem.layer))

})
```